# Get list of unique parents from childrens list

Tags: c#, linq

`Parent` has list of `Children`. I only have access to the list of children. I need to get list of unique parents from the List of Children. Is there a better/faster/more efficient way of doing it than this?

```
var temp = new HashSet<Parent>(
                        (from child in program.Children
                        select child.Parent).ToList());
```

Comment: `program.Children.Select(c => c.Parent).Distinct();`. It wont be any faster though.

Comment: It's easier to read however.

Comment: @RobH you should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of `var` is good, but names like `temp` is meaningless. It's a temp what exactly? A more descriptive name is in order here.

The call to `ToList` appears to be redundant. [`Hashset`'s constructor takes an `IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Linq queries that return collections already return one.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6262668/3198973)

I would also break the query away from the ctor for readability purposes.

```
var parents = from child in program.Children
                 select child.Parent;

var distinctParents = new HashSet<Parent>(allParents);
```

However, it's all kind of moot if you use [the method syntax snippet that @RobH posted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97946/get-list-of-unique-parents-from-childrens-list#comment179314_97946).

> ```
> var parents = program.Children.Select(c => c.Parent).Distinct();
> ```